# How does Pseudo-elements before and after to fix floats?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div which contains some thumbnails and contain few images which uses floats.
But using floats the background image/color would shrink since the images float so there's no contents for the background image/color unless I fix the length and width of background image/color.

I then found online that by using this code my problem is solved.

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}
```

I know how does clear:both works but I am not sure how did the `content: " "; display: table;` fixed the problem. I kind of guessed it but can someone simply explain to me nicely?

Thanks in advance.

I added two images in case my bad explanation is hard to understand.

[image]

[image]

Edit.  Thanks people.  Didn't know this is called clearfix no wonder I kept on typing things like :after :before  Pseudo-elements for floats or similar and I couldn't find what I need.  But I don't think this question is much of a duplex because what I wanted to ask is how the clearfix works instead of clearfix vs floats.

Thanks Prashant for the link~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason behind adding `content: " "; display: table;`  to pseudo-elements(:before ,:after ) is that --->

`:before` pseudo-element Creates an anonymous table-cell and a new block formatting context. Although this is not neccessary,This prevents top-margin collapse. The use of `table` rather than `block` is necessary to contain the top-margins of child elements.

`:after` pseudo-element is used to clear the floats.( `clear: both;` )

Source: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/